# How to navigate in my custom map?

Tags: localization, navigation, rviz, ros-hydro, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have built a map using gmapping package and i got a map.yaml file.But how should i use rviz to estimate the inital pose and how can i move my robot on rviz?

I use ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9.1

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102166/how-to-navigate-in-my-custom-map?/) by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you to take a look to the [Navigation Stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). You have to load the map with a map_server node and then you have to run a localization node (like [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)), then you can use the estimate pose 2D button on rviz to estimate your initial pose.
To move your robot you will need a planner (like [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base)) and send goals to this node.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2013-11-17**:
Thanks for your quick answer.But could you more explain how to use planner?Sorry i am new in ROS.

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-11-17**:
As I said, I suggest you to follow the Navigation Stack tutorials. You could run and study this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) to see how it uses and launches all the necessary nodes, and then try to apply it to your robot